# SharePoint On-Premises Event Receiver migration to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, event-receivers

There is a requirement to migrate SharePoint On-Premises sites to SharePoint Online (SPO). Some of the customization in the current 2013 on-prem site include Event Receivers specially ItemDeleting synchronous event. I was checking out SharePoint Webhooks but looks like sync (ing) events are not supported.

Do we have any other option to move Event Receiver in SPO Modern experience specially synchronous events?

Thank you.

Comment: Check if Remove Event receivers in SharePoint helps.

Comment: Hello @GaneshSanap, I did check Remote Event Receivers and went through some articles. We have 100+ sites where we need same event processing on libraries for ItemDeleting event. If we go with Remote Event Receivers (RER), we have to create separate Provider Hosted App/Azure Functions (associate to Library using PnP PowerShell). I think this approach will lead to 100+ Apps or Azure Functions. Please correct me if i am wrong as i do not have work experience with RER.

Comment: Hello @GaneshSanap,
I was also looking into another work around that is to hide delete options from command bar & ECB menu and implement SPFx Extension for Delete. Here i can hide Delete in command bar but now sure how to hide Delete option in ECB menu.

Not sure if there is another way/work around. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is it advisable to hide Delete in ECB menu by trying to inject CSS via SPFx Application Customizer? There is a risk of this breaking in future if Microsoft changes anything with respect to control/class for CSS.

Comment: Yes correct. There is no out of the box way to hide the Delete option from ECB menu. You can hide it using SPFx application customizers only (you will have to take risk and hope that Microsoft will not change the id/class you are using in your code to hide this option).